# How to rename photo description in sw maps apps

Tags: android, geolocation, rename, geotagging

I have a project in SW Maps, then I have take some photos and coordinate for some region. But when I back to my office, I forget to give proper description name of the photo that have been added.
How I can rename description of the photo?
Because I can't find rename or change description photo in SW Maps.
-Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

The recent update of sw maps has this facility.  Try after updating it.